# Maintain previous context Azure Custom Question and Answering C# for BOT

Tags: c#, azure, botframework, azure-language-understanding, azure-qna-maker

I created bot using Azure Portal and connecting to Azure Custom Question and Answering (Language studio). We needed some customization so I downloaded the source code (C#) and would like to know how can i retain conversation so if user next question it understands that it knows the context if question is relevant to previous question? Basically building ChatGPT like bot and is there a way that we can format the response of Answer. Sometime the Answers are given in form - "Not" , so instead if it can reply and add relevant content based on the question so it makes little more nice. We are trying to build a internal chat bot which will be based on company policy, faq etc.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the provided information, one possible solution is to use `multi-turn conversations` in Azure QnA Maker.

This allow you to manage the multiple turns of a conversation, where the previous question's context influences the next question and answer.
You can use follow-up prompts to create multiple turns of a conversation.

Please check multi-turn conversations [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/qnamaker/how-to/multi-turn) for detailed steps.

You can also check out [sample code](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/05.multi-turn-prompt) for multi turn prompt and [QnA Custom Bot](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/48.customQABot-all-features) with multi-turn conversation in BotBuilder-Samples.